# In the event of a tie, how are FedExCup points distributed among tied golfers?

Tags: statistics, pga-tour

Looking at the [FedExCup point distribution](http://www.pgatour.com/fedexcup/fedexcup-point-distribution--pga-tour-season.html), point values are assigned to golfers finishing in the 1st through 85th positions of a PGA Tour sanctioned tournament.

However, **in the event of a tie, how are FedExCup points distributed among tied golfers?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FedExCup Overview](http://www.pgatour.com/fedexcup/fedexcup-overview.html) states:

> the total points for each of the tying positions are divided equally
>   among all players in the tying position

For example, five golfers tie for second during a *PGA tour event* of a PGA Tour sanctioned tournament.

Second place alone would have accrued 300 FedExCup points, third - 190, fourth - 135, fifth - 110, and sixth - 100.

These values are added up and divided by the number of golfers who tied. "The total points for each of the tying positions" in this example is 835. Five golfers tied, so therefore, "divided equally among all players in the tying position," each golfer would receive 167 FedExCup points.

Comment: What if there is a tie on Sunday at East Lake. Will it finish Sunday or could it be a playoff on Monday?

Comment: I see you wrote a [new question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/last-day-of-fedex-cup-2015-playoffs-at-east-lake-on-27-september/12131), @powder366. This question/answer is with respect to point distribution for a single PGA Tour tournament. Your question has to do with 1) playoffs/TOUR championship rankings (as points are reset), 2) final standings, and 3) tie with respect to final standings. That said, I'll look into your question.

Comment: @powder366 "A possible tie for the FedExCup ... would result in a sudden death playoff." Source - http://www.pgatour.com/fedexcup/2015/09/20/tour-championship-scenarios.html