# Can a FedEx Cup playoff be extended to a Monday?

Tags: golf, awards, pga-tour

Is it certain that the FedEx Cup is finished on the same day as the final round (Sunday) or could it be played the following day (eg, a playoff on Monday)?

Note: The rule change noted in comments applies to the US Open, not the FedEx Cup.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is extremely limited in place and scope, and is only of historical interest.

Comment: Change of rules. There will not be a 18 hole playoff on Monday anymore. Instead they will play two extra holes directly after. If still not decided it will be a sudden death-format also same day.

Comment: It's not limited in time, not off-topic and not only of historical interest. It's valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PGA Tour FedExCup Scenarios [article](http://www.pgatour.com/fedexcup/2015/09/20/tour-championship-scenarios.html):

> A possible tie for the FedExCup ... would result in a sudden death
>   playoff

---

> Is it certain that the FedexCup is finished on Sunday or could it be a play off on Monday?

As long as the sudden death playoff ends before play is called off due to darkness. If not, the playoff will continue on Monday.

Comment: Change of rules. There will not be a 18 hole playoff on Monday anymore. Instead they will play two extra holes directly after. If still not decided it will be a sudden death-format also same day.

Comment: @powder366 You are confusing two different tournaments/events. The 18 hole playoff took place with the US Open, and they decided to change the playoff to be a two hole aggregate playoff. Playing for the FedExCup has nothing to do with how the US Open decides to administer their playoff procedures.